# How to remove unwanted White spaces in Grabcut algorithms?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing

I had implemented background subtraction using Grabcut algorithm. But I had some unwanted white spaces in cropped image from source image. How to remove white spaces of cropped image.?

Steps:

1. Reading video from Camera and read a image. My input image: [image]
2. Applying Grabcut algorithm.

   cv::grabCut(image,
                   result,
                   rectangle1,
                   bgModel,fgModel,
                   1,cv::GC_INIT_WITH_RECT);
    cv::compare(result,cv::GC_PR_FGD,result,cv::CMP_EQ);
3. Cropped foreground image  from source.

   cv::Mat foreground(image.size(),CV_8UC3,cv::Scalar(255,255,255));
   image.copyTo(foreground,result);
4. My output image:

[image]

How to remove whites spaces in face area from image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of the three solutions. Each of these should be applied to your result extracted area (i.e. the area derived after using Grabcut algorithm):

### Solution 1

For each pixel lying on the border of your extracted area:

1. Take close neighbourhood of this pixel that also belongs to the boundary of your extracted object.
2. Fit a straight **line A** to the pixels belonging to this neighbourhood (openCV has a function that does it: [fitline()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=fitline#fitline))
3. Calculate a **line B** that is perpendicular to the fitted line.
4. Remove/colour pixels that lie on the **line B** and belong to your area extracted with the Grabcut algorithm.

If in your application user may apply this operation manually, e.g. by clicking the image and choosing some option, then the algorithm given above solves the problem at this stage- user can perform this as many times as needed, removing some fixed, hard-coded number of pixels along the **B line** each time the operation is performed or providing the number of pixels that should be removed each time the operation is invoked.

If it is to be performed **without any user interaction**, another problem is determining how many pixels along the **line B** should be removed. The solution to this problem depends on how similar the images you are going to process are and whether the background is uniform or may significantly vary in colour gradient. You can e.g. compare values of the pixels lying on the border against the mean pixel value of the background (or a part of the background, if the background is not of uniform colour) - if they are ***similar enough*** (and you have to figure out, what is ***similar enough*** for your particular application), the pixel is removed.

### Solution 2

Iterate through the boundary pixels and compare their values against the background pixel value (details in **solution 1**). If the value of the pixel is ***similar enough*** (see: **solution 1**) to the background value, remove the pixel.

### Solution 3

Every time user applies this operation, border pixels are just removed without cheking their values. The depth of this operation (i.e. the number of pixels being close to the edge being removed) may be either hard-coded or specified by the user. You can think of it as a kind of **image erosion**.

---

**Solution 1** may yield more accurate results, especially in case user is supposed to perform this operation manually, while **solution 2** is much easier to implement and has less computational complexity.

**Solution 3** is the simplest, but also the most inaccurate, since every time the operation is performed, the whole picture gets cropped, and not only the part that actually needs cropping. In many cases this may be hardly visible at all though, so it might also be worth trying. Also, this solution is suitable only if the user is to perform this operation manually (since the algorithm won't be able to determine how many pixels should be removed).

Comment: Solution 3 solves my problem. Using "Dilate" and "Erode", removes the white pixels.

Comment: I am glad that it has worked for you. Did you also try other methods?